# Caffe gaussian why do different std values make such big differences for training a network

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I have been trying to train a network. And my network would not converge. But when I changed my gaussian std from 0.01 to 0.0001 my network converged really nicely. Can anyone explain that to me? What is the big difference here? Another experience I have made is that `xavier` filler produced even worse results.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No one can give you an explanation with so little detail, and I don't this question is answerable even if you provide the network architecture, the effect of initialization is an open question for many architectures.

Comment: Okay, so it is not weird to use 0.0001? @MatiasValdenegro

Comment: @thigi if it works then it's not weird

Comment: Okay, good to know. I am scaling my output values from [0, 255] to [0, 1] so that might be the reason why I have to reduce the std. But that is just a guess. I will try not to scale the value and see what happens. @Shai